# Best Case time complexity of Tower of Hanoi algorithm

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, recursive-datastructures

I want to know the best case complexity of Tower of Hanoi algorithm.
The algorithm that I used is
[Algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFwZt.jpg)

I have calculated the time complexity and it is T(2^n -1) and Big O is O(n).
But what is the best case complexity and how to calculate it?

Comment: You should write the algorithm into the question (image hosting can break, and code is better read as text). You should write out your steps for arriving at that complexity, so that we can find where your error is.  It is [well-known](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Tower_of_Hanoi&action=edit&section=7) that this algorithm is Big-Theta(2^n) -- its best case, and worst-case, when moving `n` disks from one side to another is 2^n.

Comment: The towers of Hanoi algorithm only has n as its input, and is deterministic. There is no meaningful "best" or "worst" case to consider, because there is only one "case" for each input size.

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrectly calculated the time complexity.

The correct **recurrence** can be represented by:

T(n) = 2*T(n-1) + 1 .... eq(1)

T(n) = (2^2)*T(n-2) + 1 + 2  .... eq(2)

T(n) = (2^3)*T(n-3) + 1 + 2 + 2^2 ....eq(3)

Therefore,

T(n) = (2^k)*T(n-k) + (2^0) + (2^1) + (2^2) + .... + (2^(k-1)) .... eq(4)

Now, substituting, `n-k = 1` in eq(4), we get,

T(k+1) = (2^k)*T(1) + ((2^k) + 1)

Substituting `T(1) = 1`, we get,

T(k+1) = 2^k + 2^k + 1 = 2^(k+1) + 1 ... eq(5)

Finally, substituting `k+1 = n` in eq(5) to get the **Closed Form:**

**T(n) = 2^n + 1**

**Now, the answer to your question:**

The algorithm takes O(2^n) just to print out the steps, therefore the best case time complexity also remains exponential, i.e., O(2^n).

Therefore, you cannot find any better algorithm.